# R readr read_table with trailing whitespace generates extra logical column

Tags: r, whitespace, readr

Reading the following where the '.' indicates a space character

[image]

with readr::read_table produces this data frame

[image]

with a logical column for the trailing whitepsace after the C column, in addition to the 3 columns expected for the data.

The final spurious column can be deleted after reading, but is there a way with read_table to prevent this column being generated in the first place? (read.table from base R seems to work OK).

Comment: can you just drop the column after import?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes, I mentioned deleting after reading but was after a way to prevent this happening at all. It feels like a bug, but wondered whether there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe read_table() is getting confused by the space after 'C' in the first row. One work-around is to supply the column names to the `col_names` argument, and set `skip = 1` to skip the first row of the text file.  Another way would be to just manually remove the space after 'C' in the text file.

```
read_table("myfile.txt", col_names = c("A", "B","C"), skip = 1)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
```